# Problem displaying symbols when using itemize

Tags: symbols, lists, itemize

I am currently working on a cook book and want to show some facts in the recipes with `cookingsymbols.sty`. I have problems displaying the symbols in a bullet list without the bullets. I already tried several different variants of writing it but keep getting errors. Can someone please direct me in the right direction?

```
\begin{infos}{}
\item[] \cookingtime{2 hours}  \\
\item[] \servings{2 persons}   \\
\item[] \oventime{180 degrees}
\end{infos}
```

I am using my own `recipe.sty` with the following code:

```
\newcommand{\cookingtime}[1]{\Interval & \hspace{-0.3cm} #1}
\newcommand{\servings}[1]{{\Large \Dish} & \hspace{-0.3cm} #1}
\newcommand{\oventime}[1]{{\Large \Oven} & \hspace{-0.3cm} #1}
\newcommand{\stovetime}[1]{{\Large \Gloves} & \hspace{-0.3cm} #1}

\newenvironment{infos}{
{\large {\bf Hard Facts}} \\
\par\smallskip
\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemsep}{-0.3cm}
}{
\end{itemize}
}
```

The errror I'm getting is the following:

```
Misplaced alignment tab character &. [\item[] \cookingtime{2 hours}]
```

Here is a minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cookingsymbols}

\newcommand{\cookingtime}[1]{\Interval & \hspace{-0.3cm} #1}
\newcommand{\servings}[1]{{\Large \Dish} & \hspace{-0.3cm} #1}
\newcommand{\oventime}[1]{{\Large \Oven} & \hspace{-0.3cm} #1}
\newcommand{\stovetime}[1]{{\Large \Gloves} & \hspace{-0.3cm} #1}

\newenvironment{infos}{
    {\large {\bf Hard Facts}} \\
    \par\smallskip
    \begin{itemize}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{-0.3cm}
}{
    \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{infos}{}
\item[] \cookingtime{2 hours}  \\
\item[] \servings{2 persons}   \\
\item[] \oventime{180 degrees}
\end{infos}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, please post a full minimal example that others can copy and test. It is very hard to help when one does not know how the macros are defined.

Comment: @dasbabs Apparently the error comes from the `\cookingtime` command (which you didn't post) because the code you posted compiles fine if you replace them by, say, `\textbf`.

Comment: I've added the command as well. I'm sorry I'm pretty new to LaTeX

Comment: `\Interval`, `\servings` and `\oventime` are still missing in the MWE.

Comment: If you want a &-sign you should use `\&`.

Comment: @dasbabs Please, when you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), make sure that *everything* necessary to reproduce the problem is there. For example, in your latest edit, you introduced `\Interval`, which isn't defined anywhere. Anyway, the problem is that `&` in the definition of `\cookingtime`. This `&` can't appear there. What do you want it to do?

Comment: Sorry, I thought one example would do it. In my understanding the use of interval, Large dish, etc. is is coming from cookingsymbols (\usepackage{cookingsymbols}). @dexteritas there should be no &-sign - just the symbol and a space next to it. It works when removing the &-sign in the commands for the symbols. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @dasbabs Sorry, I overlooked the `cookingsymbols` package there. My bad :/ But yes, usually one example is all we need. Just make sure that this example works (or, in your case, works except for *one* thing that doesn't) and doesn't contain too much unrelated stuff. That's basically the definition of the MWE we always ask ([see this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6256/134574)). Anyway, I think dexteritas solved it for you :) Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik No worries :) Thank you for your help! I promise will do the MWE much better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to align the lines you could use a `tabular` instead of `itemize`.
Because `\Interval` is not found I defined a dummy command for that.

If you want to adapt the spacing between the columns you can use `@{\hskip 5pt}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cookingsymbols}

\newcommand{\Interval}{Int}

\newcommand{\cookingtime}[1]{\Interval & #1}
\newcommand{\servings}[1]{{\Large \Dish} & #1}
\newcommand{\oventime}[1]{{\Large \Oven} & #1}
\newcommand{\stovetime}[1]{{\Large \Gloves} & #1}

\newenvironment{infos}{
    {\large {\bf Hard Facts}} \\
    \par\smallskip
    \begin{tabular}{r@{\hskip 5pt}l}
}{
    \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{infos}{}
\cookingtime{2 hours}  \\
\servings{2 persons}   \\
\oventime{180 degrees}
\end{infos}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution that uses the `enumitem` package to define `infos` as a new `itemize`-like list:

- With `\newlist`, you just define a new environment (here: `\begin{infos}...\end{infos}`) copying all the settings from an existing list environment (here: `itemize`) for a predefined number of nesting levels (you just need one level here).
- With `\setlist`, you change the properties of the list. See the [`enumitem` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) for a full list of available settings. Here, I added the headline with the `before` key, and set some lengths (all customizable).
- You can then use `\item[...]` inside your `infos` environment and put the respective symbol in the optional argument. For convenience, I defined some macros (as in your original example) as shorthands.
- Note here: To have a better vertical alignment of the symbols and the text, I decided to use `\raisebox` to lower the symbols a bit. This is of course customizable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cookingsymbols}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{infos}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[infos]{%
    before={\noindent\textbf{\large Hard Facts}\\[-1.2\baselineskip]},
    itemsep=-2pt,
    itemindent=-5pt,
}

\newcommand{\servings}{\item[\raisebox{-2pt}{\Large\Dish}]}
\newcommand{\oventime}{\item[\raisebox{-2pt}{\Large\Oven}]}
\newcommand{\stovetime}{\item[\raisebox{-2pt}{\Large\Gloves}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{infos}
    \servings 2 persons
    \oventime 180 degrees
    \stovetime 2 hours
\end{infos}

\end{document}
```

[image]